# Click noise when recording audio with a web audio worklet

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, web-audio-api

I created an electron app that records audio with an audio worklet node by storing the chunks into an array and later on sending the recorded chunks to the main process to write a wav file. The worklet does also compute metering and checks if values clipped however these computations take place in an async function without the process function waiting for it to resolve to prevent buffer underruns. Furthermore for direct monitoring the input stream is connected to a media stream destination node. This whole setup works pretty good most of the time but for a small amount of the recorded audio files there are significant clicking noises at random parts of the files. The strange thing is that you do not hear these clicking sounds at the direct monitoring output. When looking at the wave form of the files it seems that some samples are simply missing what also shows up in the spectrogram:

[waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n63qo.png)
[spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb2eo.png)

I measured the time the process method would take for each run and logging the parts where it would take longer than 2.9ms (128 samples / 44100 kHz mono => ~2.9ms) and sometimes it took longer than that but the clicking noises would not appear at those parts. Is it even possible for the web audio api for buffer underruns to appear or is there some internal buffer and the latency just gets worse when this happens? I just can't figure out where the clicking comes from. Below are the relevant parts of the code.

Worklet code:

```js
const statsWindowSize = 1024 * 8; // ~5 stats per second for 44kHz
const clipThreshold = 0.98;

/* eslint-disable */
class RecordingWorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isRecording = false;
    this.clipping = false;
    this.sampleIndex = 0;
    this.sum = 0;
    this.recordedBuffers = [];
    this.writeIndex = 0;

    this.port.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
      if (data.type === 'startRecording') {
        this.writeIndex = 0;
        this.recordedBuffers = [];
        this.isRecording = true;
      } else if (data.type === 'stopRecording') {
        this.port.postMessage({
          type: 'recording',
          buffers: this.recordedBuffers,
        });
        this.isRecording = false;
      }
    };
  }

  async computeStats(buffer) {
    // ...removed to shorten the code snipped
  }

  process(inputs, outpus, parameters) {
    const t0 = Date.now();
    const writeIndex = this.writeIndex;
    this.writeIndex += 1;

    // Select the first input's first channel
    const buffer0 = inputs[0][0];
    // const { windowSize, clipThreshold, isRecording } = parameters;
    if (this.isRecording) {
      // Clone the data into a new Float32Array
      const f32Buffer = new Float32Array(buffer0.length);
      f32Buffer.set(buffer0);
      this.recordedBuffers.splice(writeIndex, 0, f32Buffer);
    }

    // Detach the stats computation to prevent underruns
    this.computeStats(buffer0);

    // this.lastRunFinished = true;
    if (this.isRecording) {
      const t1 = Date.now();
      const elapsedTime = t1 - t0;
      if (elapsedTime > (128 / 44100) * 1000) {
        const atPosition = (writeIndex * 128) / 44100;
        this.port.postMessage({ type: 'underrun', elapsedTime, atPosition });
      }
    }
    // Keep processor alive
    return true;
  }
}
/* eslint-enable */

registerProcessor('recording-worklet-processor', RecordingWorkletProcessor);
```

The code that writes the wave file:

```js
// before these parts recordedBuffers will be send from the worklet via postMessage
// Merge all buffers from channel 1 into a single Float32Array
const totalByteLength = recordedBuffers.reduce(
  (total, buf) => total + buf.byteLength,
  0,
);
const header = Header({
  sampleRate: ctx.sampleRate,
  channels: 1,
  bitsPerSample: 32,
  audioFormat: IEEE_FLOAT,
  byteLength: totalByteLength,
});
const wstream = createWriteStream(audioFilePath);
wstream.write(header);
// RealBuffer is just an alias for the node Buffer type
const chunks = RealBuffer.allocUnsafe(totalByteLength);
let offset = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < recordedBuffers.length; i++) {
  const typedArray = recordedBuffers[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < typedArray.length; j++) {
    chunks.writeFloatLE(typedArray[j], offset);
    offset += typedArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  }
}
wstream.write(chunks);
wstream.end();
```

The module that creates the header:

```js
import { RealBuffer } from 'utils/io'; // An alias for the node Buffer type

export const PCM = 1;
export const IEEE_FLOAT = 3;

export const Header = ({
  sampleRate,
  channels,
  bitsPerSample,
  byteLength,
  audioFormat,
}) => {
  let offset = 0;
  const buffer = RealBuffer.allocUnsafe(44);

  const writeString = (str) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
      buffer.writeUInt8(str.charCodeAt(i), offset + i);
    }
    offset += str.length;
  };

  const writeUint32 = (value) => {
    buffer.writeUInt32LE(value, offset);
    offset += 4;
  };

  const writeUint16 = (value) => {
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(value, offset);
    offset += 2;
  };

  const blockAlign = channels * (bitsPerSample / 8);
  const byteRate = sampleRate * blockAlign;
  const chunkSize = (byteLength / 8) - 8;

  writeString('RIFF'); // ChunkID
  writeUint32(chunkSize); // ChunkSize
  writeString('WAVE'); // Format
  writeString('fmt '); // Subchunk1ID
  writeUint32(16); // Subchunk1Size
  writeUint16(audioFormat); // AudioFormat (PCM=1,IEEE Float=3,...)
  writeUint16(channels); // Channels
  writeUint32(sampleRate); // SampleRate
  writeUint32(byteRate); // ByteRate
  writeUint16(blockAlign); // BlockAlign
  writeUint16(bitsPerSample); // BitsPerSample
  writeString('data'); // Subchunk2ID
  writeUint32(byteLength); // Subchunk2Size
  return buffer;
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `process` function you always create a new array in `f32buffer` every time the function is called.  This needs to be collected eventually, so I'm guessing the glitches are caused by GC collecting all the garbage you've created.

You can get more details using chrome://tracing to get information about this.  Press record, then Edit Categories and select blink_gc and webaudio and maybe audio.  Then record a trace and examine the graphs to see what's happening.